# Installing .exe or tar.gz depending the os using Ant

Tags: java, ant, operating-system, conditional-statements

I need your help.

I want to install a file (.exe) if I am on a 32 bits OS or install(gunzip) a .tar.gz file if I am on 64 bits OS.

I have the following code but not working :

```
<target name="installJava7">

        <condition property="java7pack" value="${java7.32.src}">
            <equals arg1="${os.bitness}" arg2="32"/>
        </condition>
        <exec executable="${java7pack}" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="/s" />
            <arg value="/INSTALLDIR=${java7.install.dir}" />
        </exec>

        <condition property="java7pack" value="${java7.64b.src}">
            <equals arg1="${os.bitness}" arg2="64"/>
        </condition>
        <gunzip src="${java7pack}" dest="C:/java"/>
        <untar src="C:/System/java" dest="${java.install.dir}" overwrite="true"/>
    </target>
```

Thank you.

2) after modification :

I have 3 targets but i don't know if the "if" condition is correct.

```
    <target name="installJava7"> 
<antcall target="installJava7U60.32b" /> 
<antcall target="installJava7U60.64b" />    
<condition property="java7pack" value="${java7.src}"> 
     <equals arg1="${os.bitness}" arg2="32"/> </condition> 
<condition property="java7pack" value="${java7.64b.src}"> 
     <equals arg1="${os.bitness}" arg2="64"/> </condition> 
    </target>

<target name="installJava7.32b" if="java7pack" > 
<exec.. 
</target> 

<target name="installJava7.64b" if="java7pack" > 
<gunzip..
</target>
```

Comment: Be more clear what is not working. For example: Does the ant built run at all, or fails with an error? Or it just performs the same tasks, regardless of OS ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The ant built performs the same tasks, regardless of OS. It automatically enters the "exec" tags. I think I should write the condition correctly.. but how ?

Comment: I think you need separate targets with `if` attributes

Comment: Ok, so i need to make a target for the 32 bits and another target for the 64 bits, right ?

Comment: Yes. Then from the main target you call both targets, one after another, but only one will be executed because of the if. You would need more properties conditionally set (for example os32 and os64), because afair `if` only checks if a given property is set, irrelevant of it's value